# How to convert list returned in django context to javascript or vuejs list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, vue.js

So I have a simple list being returned in the django context

```
rlinks: ['test1', 'test2'', 'test3']

var v_root = new Vue({
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    el: '#vue-main',
    data: {
        job_execs: [],
        rlinks: '{{ rlinks }}',
```

When I do console.log from vuejs on this I see:

```
[&#39;test1&#39;, &#39;test2&#39;]
```

How do I convert the above into a javascript list?  If at all possible - I would prefer the solution be on the javascript end and not the django end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's an array of strings, you could just use `<textarea>`s:

```js
const arr = ["&#39;test1&#39;", "&#39;test2&#39;"];
const res = arr.map(e => {
  let inp = document.createElement("textarea");
  inp.innerHTML = e;
  return inp.value;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: TypeError arr.map is not a function